# Multimedia and Animation

Tags: multimedia

I need to prepare a blue print. It should be a video. A small sample of Traffic Signal working.

If the lights are green, The vehicles should pass else it should wait for the timer.

Which is the best way of doing this.
Can i do this in Flash ?
Else is there any easy way to do this ?
Can anyone guide me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it yourself, you can use Adobe Flash or SwishMax products to make it with minimal efforts.